# .ToListAsync() vs .ToList() + Task.Run

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have a WPF application.

The data is brought from the repository to the ViewModel. What would be the better way to retrieve the data:

**Method 1:**

In Repository:

```
public List<LogDetail> GetLogsOfTypeForCase(int caseId, LoggType logType)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SidraEntitiesNoChangesDetection())
        {
            var logs = (from l in ctx.Loggs
                where l.log_fk_caseid == caseId && l.log_operation == logType.ToString()
                select new LogDetail()
                {
                    ColumnName = l.log_columnname,
                    DateAndTime = l.log_dateandtime,
                    IdentificationDetail = l.log_identificationDetail,
                    NewValue = l.log_new_value,
                    OldValue = l.log_old_value,
                    TableName = l.log_tablename,
                    UserCode = l.User.usr_code
                }).ToList();

            return logs;
        }
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                if (false == this.CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    this.CaseLogs = this.dataAdapter.GetLogsOfTypeForCase(this.CaseId, LoggType.S);
                }

            },
            this.CancellationTokenSource.Token
            );
```

or
**Method 2**

In Repository:

```
public async Task<List<LogDetail>> GetLogsOfTypeForCase(int caseId, LoggType logType)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SidraEntitiesNoChangesDetection())
        {
            var logs = await (from l in ctx.Loggs
                where l.log_fk_caseid == caseId && l.log_operation == logType.ToString()
                select new LogDetail()
                {
                    ColumnName = l.log_columnname,
                    DateAndTime = l.log_dateandtime,
                    IdentificationDetail = l.log_identificationDetail,
                    NewValue = l.log_new_value,
                    OldValue = l.log_old_value,
                    TableName = l.log_tablename,
                    UserCode = l.User.usr_code
                }).ToListAsync();

            return logs;
        }
    }
```

and in ViewModel

```
protected override async void Load()
    {
           if (false == this.CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
           {
               this.CaseLogs = await this.dataAdapter.GetLogsOfTypeForCase(this.CaseId, LoggType.S);
           }
     }
```

From what I have read, Method 1 would be preferred, but what be the advantages?

Comment: Who said method 1 is preferable and what was their proof?

Comment: If you've read one of them would be preferred, surely they also said why? If you're reading someone saying something's better and not explaining, move along to the next article.

Comment: Also, whoever they are, you probably shouldn't ever listen to them. They clearly do not understand how the Task Parallel Library works...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Method 2 is preferable, because it uses one less thread.

It also can (with some modifications) properly support cancellation:

```
public async Task<List<LogDetail>> GetLogsOfTypeForCase(int caseId, LoggType logType, CancellationToken token)
{
  ...
        }).ToListAsync(token);
  ...
}

protected override async void Load()
{
  this.CaseLogs = await this.dataAdapter.GetLogsOfTypeForCase(this.CaseId, LoggType.S, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Method 2. The Async versions of these methods do all the "heavy lifting" for you, that was what they were designed for.  Task.Run() is a heavy process call, you are required to handle all the potential errors and failures yourself, you don't need a sledge hammer here, just a light weight finishing hammer.

By this I mean that you are trying to create what the framework has already done for you, this is where Async calls were meant to be used so why not just use them?